# How to do the task of "<jsp:include page="servletName" />" using Struts

Tags: jsp, servlets, struts

In my JSP page, a tag `<jsp:include page="servletName" />` has been added. Here servletName is is HttpServlet Class and that class add some attributes to Request object. Then, again in the jsp page, the values set to the request object are retrieved (this thing has been done to reduce the line of codes in the jsp page).

I want to do this in Struts 2 application.

I want to call an action class (something like `<jsp:include />` in a normal jsp application) and then that class set some values to Request object(Value Stack) . Then those values should be retrieved in the jsp class using Struts Tags.

How Can I do this?

Also, how can I send a  request parameter bound to the jsp page and send it to the action class?
 [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/59108/Struts/include-struts-action-jsp) shows something what I want:

```
<s:action name="Login" flush="true" executeResult="true" namespace="/secure"/>
```

But it is not clear for me how to write `execute()` and struts.xml and the attributes used. any one can clear it for me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`<s:action>` tag](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/action.html).

I question the need for this, however; if this is something done frequently enough to warrant this, consider using a base action class that implements Preparable, and create an app-specific sub-class means of adding behavior for actions that require their own prepare.

IMO relying on the view to add objects it needs is a violation of concern separation.

Comment: Thank you. Would you explain more how to use <s:action .. with a sample code how the struts.xml and what should action class returns.

Comment: The action isn't rendering anything--it doesn't matter what the action class returns. The config looks like any action config. The tag documentation clearly shows an example of what you're discussing--consider checking the documentation first.

Comment: Thanks MR Dave. I referred it. and tried as the doc says. But now, the content of the page is repeated many times. :( .  Here in jsp `  <s:action name="ActionName" executeResult="true" />`  In struts.xml  `<action name="ActionName" class="org.app.action.ActionName" >
        <result name="success" >/index.jsp</result>            
        </action>` .

Comment: @AashMaharoon Why would you execute the result of an action whose only purpose is to put objects into scope?

Comment: Thanks for your attention. You meant `executeResult="false"` which was earlier set to true. I changed it to false and now it is ok. Then how can I send a parameter with a value to that action ? My purpose is that, to send a parameter and get it from the action and then display values according to the parameter's value.

Comment: @AashMaharoon Please look at the tag documentation: second paragraph states "Parameters can be passed to the action using nested param tags."

Answer (score 1):

Use Struts `IncludeAction` like.

```
<jsp:include page=”/App1/legacyA.do” />

<action path=”/legacyA”
parameter=”/xoom/LegacyServletA”
type=”org.apache.struts.actions.IncludeAction” />
```